Can a slack workflow execute a script in a google spreadsheet?
If you have a google spreadsheet that runs a script that creates folders/files in google drive and pulls data from elsewhere, but needs a simple text input to get started, can a slack workflow be configured to send a text string over to the script embedded into the google spreadsheet and then execute it all? Bonus points if it can return the generated file output back into a Slack Canvas/Channel.
This is theoretical, don't have scripting knowledge.


Send string from Slack to Google Sheet using workflow.
Use Google App Script Trigger (on change) to trigger the script (choose a function to run) when the string is added into the sheet in step 1.
Your script runs and do your thing.
Send your file/folder to slack by using Slack App API/Webhook
Done

